# Feed Reader updates (Eg Google Reader or Bloglines)

Tags: batch-file, feed

What is the method through which online feed reader sites like google reader updates its feed
is it cron or something else.

Sorry if question is too basic i am still a novice in programming.

Answer (score 0):

> cron or something else

That's actually right to the point. The basic idea is that you need to run non-user-triggered scheduled work in the application to update the feeds, and how this is done depends very much on the server environment and the web framework. In a LAMP application it might be cron, in ASP.NET it might be a Windows Service or a Scheduled Task. Some web frameworks, like Ruby on Rails, have [specialized modules for this](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/howtos/background-processes).

Your only real obstacle will be finding a way to run code that is not the result of a user requesting a resource from your server.

Comment: Ah, also about Google Reader: there is an interesting optimization on the server updates - if you have a feed that is subscribed by lots of Reader user, the 'cron' will run a lot more frequently than if there is only 1 or 2 subscribers, and once it'ss updated, new items will show up for everyone. We can be talking about updates around every 2 minutes for the most popular feeds, to a couple of refreshes a day for the less popular ones.

Comment: _"Google Reader will check your subscriptions for updates about once an hour. Updates may occur a bit less frequently for feeds that have few subscribers."_ http://www.google.com/support/reader/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=70642 This is the official statement, though I have seen more frequent updates for some feeds (Gizmodo, Slashdot). This was confirmed by other people was well, but it is not official said.

Comment: @ptdev, good stuff. I wonder how @jason is coming along with their feed reader.